# Unusual initialization required to construct object in a templated class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, constructor, c++14

I have some code that is structured like so:

```
enum class Type {a,b, c, d};


template<typename T>
class External {
    public:
        External(Type t) {

        }
};


template<typename T>
class Base {};

template<typename T>
class Derived : Base<T> {
    public:
    private:
        External<int> e(Type::a);
};


int main() {
    Derived<int> der;

    return 0;
}
```

When compiled with g++, this gives the following error:

```
<source>:49:25: error: 'Type::a' is not a type
   49 |         External<int> e(Type::a);
      |                         ^~~~
```

Through some experimentation I found out that it works if I construct the object of type `External` differently:

```
template<typename T>
class Derived : Base<T> {
    public:
    private:
        External<int> e = External<int>(Type::a);
};
```

Why is that the case? Why does the compiler expect a type in the first case?

Comment: You must use `=...` or `{...}` when initializing things at class scope. Presumably to avoid ambiguity with member function declarations.

Comment: See this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization:~:text=Through%20a%20default%20member%20initializer%2C%20which,member%20initializer%20list%20of%20a%20constructor.

Comment: The templating and inheritance are irrelevant. You will encounter the same problem with `struct A { int x(0); };`

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is trying to interpret `e` as member function, so it's trying to treat `Type::a` as a type.

For [default member initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization), you can only use braced-init-list or equal-sign initializer (as you showed).

> Through a *default member initializer*, which is a brace or equals initializer included in the member declaration and is used if the member is omitted from the member initializer list of a constructor.

```
template<typename T>
class Derived : Base<T> {
    public:
    private:
        External<int> e{Type::a};
};
```

Comment: Yes. `int a(42)` would also not compile in class scope.